# Write a list of lists into csv in Python

Tags: python, list, file, csv

I have a list of lists of pure data like this

```
a=[[1,2,3],
   [4,5,6],
   [7,8,9]]
```

How can I write `a` into a CSV file with each list in a column like this?

```
1 4 7 
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: **make a Transpose of your DataFrame**                                                              
 `a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];`
   `df = pd.DataFrame(a).T;`
`df.to_csv("output.csv",index=False,header=False)`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
import csv
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(list(zip(*l)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import csv
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    writer.writerows(a)
```